# Infinite order element

Tags: group-theory

Find a group $G$ that contains elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2=e$, $b^2=e$, but the order of the element $ab$ is infinite.

**My attempt**:

Clearly $G$ cannot be abelian. So I looked at two commonly known non-abelian groups, namely

(i) [The group of symmetries of the equilateral triangle](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-group-of-symmetries-of-the-equilateral-triangle)

(ii) 2 by 2 matrices

Neither of these seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated, guys.

Comment: Think of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we can imagine involutions $a,b$ as each flipping the plane 180 degrees over some  line. If the angle between the two lines were just so...

Answer (score 2):

Consider $GL_2(R)$
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
A^2=B^2=I, (AB)^n = \begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what is the motivation for the solution, i.e. how did you arrive at it?

Comment: @Thomas, honestly, I just knew it. To get insides - you may try to use the same diagonals and 0 as lower left element in matrices replacing upper right element by x in A and by y in B, then do calculations and watch upper right element depends on n,x,y

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example is probably the free group on two elements $a, b$ with the only relations $a^2 = e$, $b^2 = e$. By the way, a finite group like symmetries of a triangle cannot have an element of infinite order.